# Create a dynamic properties file in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm writing a code where there is this properties file that needs to update every day based on date.

Basically there is an Excel sheet that has to be used as a source document for my Web App. But everyday there is a new file that gets generated, And the file name would be `workbooktoday'sDate`, like for example if the date is 06/09/2016, the file name would be `workbook20160609`, right now I'm making this in a class file, and I want to move everything to a `properties file`, currently my code is as below(In a Java class).

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
private String todayDate = dateFormat.format(date);
String replaceHyph = todayDate.replace("-", "");
String x = "workbook";
String y = ".xls";
private String excelPath = x + replaceHyph + y;
```

and in my next program I use the below statement.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + excelPath + "; READONLY=FALSE;");
```

And this would set the source filename to `workbookToday'sDate`, how can I get the same in properties file?

How can I achieve the same in my Properties file?

I thought of declaring only half part say like `jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ="`  and concatenating as I did above and at the end again concatenating `"; READONLY=FALSE;");`. Is this a good approach, or is there a better one?

Comment: Why are you first formatting the date with hyphens, and then you remove the hyphens? Just use date format `yyyyMMdd` then you don't have to remove the hyphens.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, thanks for the quick tip, I'll implement it right away, but my question is something else.

Comment: If understood your question correctly basically above you are using java jdbc driver to read Excel file. Instead of reading from Excel you can put everything in .properties file and read it using property leader.What is problem here?

Comment: Hi @amicngh, I'll have to do it everyday, when ever a new file comes. I don't want my client to touch any of the files, directly he should do his work without changing any thing.

Comment: so you want to create a property file everyday?

Comment: I don't want to, In my question there is this `excelPath `, that does the task without any human intervention, I want my properties file to be the same, daily the workbook name should be automatically created.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what advantages you think you would gain by using a properties file over your current (code) approach. If you want a new filename every day "without any human intervention" then some code is going to have to be involved *somewhere*.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, If you see my first code block, there it is how I get my file name, Here I'm no where creating a file name manually, it is done by the code itself, by concatenating `workbook` with `Today's date` (and this is the file name). I want this in a property file as I've got more than 15 Java classes that use this `dburl`, If in case there is some change, I don't want to go manually and update each and every file, but Instead, I'll just update my properties file and the references get updated.

Comment: *"Instead, I'll just update my properties file and the references get updated"* - So *you* will become the "automatic" process that updates the properties file each day to keep the filename current? That doesn't sound terribly advantageous to me, especially when you could have your 15 classes simply share the same code to derive the filename.

Comment: @GordThompson, I don't think I got that point, do you suggest me to create a class and do as I used to earlier? don't use properties file? Just a bit confused. :-(

Comment: Yes. That approach makes more sense.

Comment: @GordThompson, Ohk, Thank you Sir. I'll implement this right away...